# Flutter amplify - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, flutter-aws-amplify

I was trying to install Amplify libraries in my Flutter project in the process I am trying to Provision the backend with Amplify CLI.
I am following [official docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/create-application/q/platform/flutter/) to configure this. on the 3rd step while giving amplify init command on the terminal it throws an error & I didn't find a solution anywhere could you guys help me out? Below is the screenshot of the error. If you want any more info I can provide it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my keys I cross-checked the credentials in the .aws folder and I edit with the right one it working fine now.